# Can LWCs be used to create an entire page?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

All the code samples about LWC involve creating a single, tiny component that renders a form, or a card, etc. I get it that the industry has moved towards creating smaller components/services, and then using them together to create something bigger.

Sometimes however, you just want to create a single page, with the sidebar, header and all as part of the same file, because those components (sidebar, header, etc) won't be reusable outside of the context of that specific page.

Visualforce pages naturally allowed for this type of development, by providing tags that mirrored Salesforce standard pages (think pageBlock, blockSection, etc).

The concrete question is: is it possible to create an entire page with a single LWC ala visualforce style? Are there any limitations on how the CSS and Javascript of a LWC file work that would make this complicated or not straight forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An LWC needs a "container" of some sort, as it cannot *directly* be a page. However, it's easy enough to build an app like this:

```
<aura:application>
  <c:myLWC />
</aura:application>
```

LWC's leverage standard browser functionality as much as possible, so they should perform just about as well as native HTML.

If you want to build a SPA (Single Page Application), you're certainly welcome to, it just needs to be contained inside either a Lightning App or Visualforce page.

Aside from the need to be wrapped within Lightning Out (Visualforce) or a Lightning App, it should have the same general behavior you'd expect as building a ton of small components. I suspect that such an app would probably be even easier to build compared to using components, as the CSS, data access, etc would be relatively simplified.

Comment: are there tags in LWC that mirror the salesforce pages? block section, section header, section item, etc?

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan Sort of. Things like "page blocks" are artifacts of an aging user interface. Instead, we have things like Cards, Accordion, Menus, and so on. And these are LWC components provided by the system library. There isn't a perfect correlation between all components, because the UI is inherently different. Not all UI elements are available out of the box, so we also have the [Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com) page to help us create the UI. You can use as much or as little of the standard library as you'd like.